# how to notify customer when admin puts into hold status from grid?

Tags: orders, order-status, order-grid

In admin side sales order grid screen we can select orders & we can put into hold status.but in this case there is no possibility for notifying customers.

When we are open that order there is a section for notifying customers with check box.

but i want to put orders into hold status from grid & notify to customers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following code : 
Create a file /app/etc/modules/Namespace_Custmail.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <config>
        <modules>
            <Namespace_Custmail>
                <active>true</active>
                <codePool>community</codePool>
            </Namespace_Custmail>
        </modules>
    </config>
```

**/app/code/community/Namespace/Custmail/etc/config.xml**

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Namespace_Custmail>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Namespace_Custmail>
    </modules>

    <global>
        <models>
            <custmail>
                <class>Namespace_Custmail_Model</class>
            </custmail>
        </models>
        <events>
            <sales_order_save_commit_after>
                <observers>
                    <mail_status_change>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>custmail/observer</class>
                        <method>invoicedStatusChange</method>
                    </mail_status_change>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_save_commit_after>
        </events>
        <template>
            <email>
                <custom_order_tpl module="Namespace_Custmail">
                    <label>Status Mail Invoice</label>
                    <file>statusmail_processing.html</file>
                    <type>html</type>
                </custom_order_tpl>
            </email>
        </template>
    </global>
</config>
```

**/app/code/community/Namespace/Custmail/Model/Observer.php**

```
class Namespace_Custmail_Model_Observer
{
    public function invoicedStatusChange($event)
    {
        $order = $event->getOrder();
        $orderStatus = $order->getStatus();
        if ($order->getState() == Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_HOLDED)
            $this->_sendStatusMail($order);
    }

    private  function _sendStatusMail($order)
    {
        $emailTemplate  = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');

        $emailTemplate->loadDefault('custom_order_tpl');
        $emailTemplate->setTemplateSubject('Your order was holded');

        // Get General email address (Admin->Configuration->General->Store Email Addresses)
        $salesData['email'] = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/email');
        $salesData['name'] = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/name');

        $emailTemplate->setSenderName($salesData['name']);
        $emailTemplate->setSenderEmail($salesData['email']);

        $emailTemplateVariables['username']  = $order->getCustomerFirstname() . ' ' . $order->getCustomerLastname();
        $emailTemplateVariables['order_id'] = $order->getIncrementId();
        $emailTemplateVariables['store_name'] = $order->getStoreName();
        $emailTemplateVariables['store_url'] = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB);
        $emailTemplate->send($order->getCustomerEmail(), $order->getStoreName(), $emailTemplateVariables);
    }
}
```

**/app/locale/en_US/template/email/statusmail_processing.html**

```
<div>
    <h1>Dear {{var username}}</h1>
    <p>Your order #{{var order_id}} was canceled for some reasons… </p>
    <div>{{var storename}} ({{var store_url}})</div>
</div>
```

[For More Info read here](http://www.atwix.com/magento/emails-for-custom-events)